# Android interface part

Tags: java, android, interface

what is that and how I can execute it in my app? Maybe some helpful links?[image: interface]

Comment: sry for the size(( I posted from my phone

Comment: What is this question and how anyone can ever answer such questions? Maybe some helpful details?

Comment: It's QuickAction, I found [russian](http://helloandroid.ru/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83/2011/01/08/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-quickaction-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-android/) post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is **quickaction dialog** find below tutorial how we use quickaction dialog in our application

[How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)